# TypeNotPresentException thrown when reflecting on a method

Tags: java, android, reflection

I've got a sub class that has a method that throws an exception in an Android project.

```java
public class Bar extends Foo {
    public void method(String someClass) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        Class.forName(someClass);
    }
}
```

I've got a base class with a method that reflects on its own methods which, of course, can be called from the subclass.

```java
public class Foo {
    public void reflectOnMethods() {
        for (Method m : this.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
           //do stuff with methods
        }
    }
}
```

And when Bar calls its inherited reflectOnMethods, I'm presented with a stack trace like so

```java
02-05 21:58:04.461: E/AndroidRuntime(2737): java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type java/lang/ReflectiveOperationException not present
02-05 21:58:04.461: E/AndroidRuntime(2737):     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Native Method)
02-05 21:58:04.461: E/AndroidRuntime(2737):     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:703)
```

The issue goes away when I change the thrown exception from `ReflectiveOperationException` to `ClassNotFoundException` but ***WHY IS THAT THE FIX??!!?***

I'm puzzled by it and would look into the JDK source to try to figure it out but I'm feeling lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to run the code on API <19, but the `ReflectiveOperationException` is base class for `ClassNotFoundException`, `IllegalAccessException`, `InstantiationException`, `InvocationTargetException`, `NoSuchFieldException` and `NoSuchMethodException` since API 19.

Do not use `ReflectiveOperationException` in throws clause if you want compatibility with API levels below 19.

```
public class Bar extends Foo {
    public void method(String someClass) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName(someClass);
    }
}
```